# Sobrepor Div com Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Bom dia.

Eu estou utilizando o Bootstrap para desenvolver um site e eu estou usando uma Navbar e uma Div com uma imagem,
porem quando eu insiro a navbar e a div com a imagem, a div começa logo abaixo da Navbar e não era isso que eu esperava.

Basicamente o que eu quero e sobrepor essa imagem com a navbar, ou seja, fazer a div começar no canto superior da tela e a navbar também, sobrepondo a div.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Eu já tentei usar o z-index, porém não consegui setar um valor que sobreponha minha div.

Desde já, agradeço pela ajuda.

---

Edit:
Essa parte do código é basicamente isso:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMain" aria-controls="navbarMain" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMain">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="solu.html">Soluções</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="prod.html">Produtos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="abt.html">Sobre</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div style="min-height: 100vh;width: 100%;background-color: blue">
    <p>Div</p>
</div>
```

Uma div de tela inteira e uma navbar que tem que sobrepor ela, perceba que o texto "div" ta embaixo da navbar, queria q ele "sumisse atras da navbar"

Comment: Posta um exemplo do seu código.

Comment: Sem código e uma amostra visual do problema fica difícil achar uma solução.

Comment: Editei e coloquei uma amostra do código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar o `z-index` a sua `<div>` tem que ter um `position` setado, no caso a NavBar tem o `z-index:0` por *default*, então para jogar a `div azul` para baixo coloquei nela `position: relative;` e `z-index: -1;` e usei o `top: -56px;` para ela alinhar no topo da página.

```
div.azul {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    top: -56px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

***Veja funcionando aqui:*** (coloquei o texto grande para vc ver que ele está indo por traz da NavBar ok, depois vc retira)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name=
 content=
>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
  div.azul {
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
        top: -56px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
        font-size: 70px;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMain" aria-controls="navbarMain" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMain">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="solu.html">Soluções</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="prod.html">Produtos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="abt.html">Sobre</a>
        </li>w
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="azul">
      <p>Div</p>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo, só uma outra coisa que meio que não entendi foi de onde veio o "top: -56px;" (os 56px é uma medida exata, tamanho da navbar ou o que?), porém isso resolveu meu problema.

Comment: @Targaryen que bom que deu certo! O o "top: -56px;" é para fazer a Div Azul subir por traz da NavBar até o topo da janela. Se vc tirar a cor do BG da NavBar, vc vai ver a Div Azul tocando na parte superior da janela. Pelo menos foi isso que eu entendi que vc queria rss. Se a minha resposta era o que vc precisava considere marcar a Resposta com "Aceita" `✔`